# Python attribute error object has no attribute

Tags: python, oop

When I apply two underscores I get the error `AttributeError: 'Organization' object has no attribute '__employees'`
Here is the code.

```
 class Organization(object):
        __employees=[]

    google=Organization()
    google.__employees.append('Erik')
```

Python doesn't implement private variable concept. If so what I get error. If I remove one underscore code execute without an error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you have declared it as a private variable.

```
>>> class Organization(object):
...     __employees = []
... 
>>> google = Organization()
>>> google._Organization__employees.append('Erik')
>>> google._Organization__employees
['Erik']

>>> dir(Organization)
['_Organization__employees', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

As you can see it save your vairable name with **_Classname__Variablename**.
In your case it is **_Organization__employees**.

From the [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references)s:

> Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores,
>   at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
>   _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard
>   to the syntactic position of the identifier, so it can be used to
>   define class-private instance and class variables, methods, variables
>   stored in globals, and even variables stored in instances. private to
>   this class on instances of other classes.